# only print arXiv number for unpublished articles with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, arxiv

I'm using the option `eprint=false` in `\usepackage{biblatex}`, as in

```
\usepackage[giveninits=true,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false,backend=bibtex,style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
```

so that it does not print the arXiv reference for published articles. However, I have certain entries (currently listed as `@online` in my `.bib` file, but I could also list them as `@artice` if needed) that have not yet been published and only have arXiv numbers.

Would it be possible to print arXiv number only for the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things you could to do show the `eprint` field for certain entries while suppressing it for others. You just need to figure out a rule that says when to print and when not to print `eprint` and a way to tell `biblatex` about that.

With a recent version of `biblatex` you could for example turn off `eprint` globally with `eprint=false,` and then turn it back on for only `@online` entries. (Here the rule would be that published papers are entered as `@article` and preprints that are not yet published in a journal as `@online`.)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
  style=verbose-trad2,
  giveninits=true,
  doi=false, isbn=false, url=false, eprint=false,
]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[online]{eprint=true}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{baez/article,baez/online} % both entries have an eprint field
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Baez, J. C. and A. D. Lauda. Higher-Dimensional Algebra V: 2-Groups. Version 3. 27th Oct. 2004. arXiv: math/0307200v3.//— ‘Higher-Dimensional Algebra V: 2-Groups’. Version 3. In: Theory and Applications of Categories 12 (2004), pp. 423–491.]

It is also possible to use entry-level options.

Alternatively, you could skip the option and modify the relevant bibmacros directly, which would give you more possibilities for fine tuning which `eprint`s are shown (you could check if `eprinttype` is `arxiv` for example). I'll be happy to write something up about that, but then I'd need a good example document with good test `.bib` entries and a clearer description of the rules/algorithms that determine if a `eprint` is shown or not.

Comment: Thanks, the ExecuteBibliographyOptions does exactly the job I needed.